# How can i get the current applied route in CraftCMS?

Tags: templating, localization, routes, multi-site, routing

I'm using a dynamic route that loads a template. I'm on a multisite setup with a language switch in the header menu.

To be able to switch between sites or languages, the dynamic routes need to have some sort of connection.

I figured out you can define routes in a site-specific context and add extra attributes (e.g. 'name') like this:

```
//routes.php file
return [
  'enSite' => [
      'example/{tag}' => ['template' => 'example/_index.html',
                          'name' => 'example',
                         ],
  ],
  'nlSite' => [
      'voorbeeld/{tag}' => ['template' => 'voorbeeld/_index.html',
                            'name' => 'example',
                           ],
  ],
];
```

Now I can tell craft that the routes with the same `name` are variants of each other for the language switcher.

All i need now is the "current applied route". I can't find this information anywhere. I was expecting it in `craft.app.requestedRoute`, but that's not the case.

Does anyone know how to get the current applied route in Craft?

Others with similar issues loop over `craft.app.routes.getConfigFileRoutes` and match on the route keys, but with tokens like `{tag}` in your roue this is not an option.

Comment: Check this: http://craftsnippets.com/articles/url-macro - looks like it might be solving what you're trying to do, using macros.

Comment: Thanks, but most of the stuff I tried is already based on that article. In the code snippets from the article, they loop over the  `craft.app.routes.getConfigFileRoutes`  . The currently applied route is never fetched.